# Assignment problem with multiple assignments and constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I have a bi-partite graph $G=(P \cup C,E)$ where $P$ contains 'parents', these parents are in pairs, but count as one vertex, and are to be matched with a number of children in the set $C$. I want to add a constraint that 'families', that is a group of pairings, should have $c$ children such that $1 \leq c \leq 4$ (Ideally it would be evenly spread but that doesn't really matter.)

I will have a cost function $\lambda: P \times C \to \mathbb{R}$ that will, given a parent-pair and some information about them and a child give a score of how good a pairing they would be. Presume this function is given.

The goal: to have families all matched as well as possible (i.e. maximise $\lambda$ either in each case, or as an average overall, or smth) as per the function $\lambda$. Cost is not determined based on other children already in the family, *just* the parents. Can anyone point me to an algorithm that could solve this, or requires minimal modification to solve it?

I cannot brute force as that would be $\mathcal{O}(N!)$ and my inputs could be as large as $N=500$. Note: since this is for practical usage a non-perfect but very good solution is acceptable. Although, I'd obviously love a perfect solution.

I have seen the Hungarian Algorithm but I don't know how I'd modify it to allow multiple assignments per parent-pair. If it can be done please refer me to a source stating how :)

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce three additional copies of each node in $P$, yielding $4|P|$ parent nodes, and also introduce $4|P|-|C|$ dummy child nodes to balance the two sides of the bipartition.  To force at least one real child per parent, impose a large negative $\lambda$ for the first parent node out of each four to each dummy child node.  All other pairs $(p,c)$ where $c$ is a dummy child node have $\lambda(p,c) = 0$.  Now solve the usual $n \times n$ maximum assignment problem with the Hungarian algorithm or otherwise.

An alternative approach is solve a transportation problem in the original network, with a (variable) supply in $[1,4]$ for each parent node, and a demand of at most $1$ per child.  You can use a network flow solver or a linear programming solver.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go! Just did a lecture on all of this and remembered I had this problem to solve, however it only explained how to do it for equally sized sets and pairs